# How to add a full page sized background link?

Tags: html

I have made a page that grants me access to a lot of nice websites of the web, so I don't have to type in all the links.

I want to use this page for my site www.x3mismusic.eu for a index of all the songs, but since there is no place for a home button, I'd like to make the full page clickable as a link. I made it so that whenever you use shift+x links will be disabled so that you can click trough the buttons. However even though I put a link on the background it doesn't show it and it also doesn't work.

I tried to put a link (anchor tag) around body, create a second wrap with a link and I even tried to use the JavaScript "onclick" tag in the body, but that didn't work like I wanted, because onclick makes me unable to use the button links I created.

I surfed the web for ages but couldn't find any reason or solution for why the link doesn't work. Can someone please help me with making the background clickable as a link, while being able to still activated the button links?

I am not good at formatting code in here so I'll have a jsfiddle link to the code. Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/e5fm5byn/

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/e5fm5byn/" target="_blank">because it asked me 
to input code</a>
```

Comment: I've tidied up this question from a lower-case post to one that is a bit more readable. However if you can copy the fiddle back to your question, that is appreciated - the requirement for code is specifically to discourage fiddle-only posts. Please don't work around the rules - they are there for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

Hie there
you should not have multiple `id`'s with same value
and now coming to your question

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .disableMenu {
            pointer-events:none;
        }
        .x {
            background-color:#000;
            color:#600;
            padding-left:50px;
            padding-right:50px;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-bottom:5px;
            border:3px solid #600;
            text-align:center;
            float:left;
        }
        .x:hover {
            background-color:#000;
            color:#0a0;
            padding-left:50px;
            padding-right:50px;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-bottom:5px;
            border:3px solid #0a0;
            text-align:center;
            float:left;
        }
        a {
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a:hover {
            color:#b89200;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        body {
            background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #123264, #606);
            color:#b89200;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #wrapper {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            left:0%;
            top:0%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #wrapper2 {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            left:0%;
            top:0%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onkeypress="IEKeyCap()" onclick="myClickEvent(this)">
    <div id="wrapper"> 
        <span class="x">
            <b>
                youtubeX
            </b>
        </span>
        </a> 
        <a href="http://www.lunagang.nl" target="_blank" title="lunagang">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    lunagang
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" title="facebook">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    facebook
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="http://46.21.172.161:2222/CMD_LOGIN" target="_blank" title="direct                   admin">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    direct admin
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a href="http://46.21.172.161/squirrelmail/src/login.php" target="_blank" title="squirrelmail">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    squirrelmail
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a href="http://www.runescape.com" target="_blank" title="runescape">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    runescape
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="google">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    google
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a href="http://www.x3mismusic.eu" target="_blank" title="x3mis music">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    x3mis music
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a href="http://www.game-vortex.eu" target="_blank" title="game-vortex">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    game-vortex
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a href="http://www.outlook.com" target="_blank" title="outlook">
            <span class="x">
                <b>
                    outlook
                </b>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function NNKeyCap(thisOne) {
     if (thisOne.modifiers & Event.SHIFT_MASK) {
         if (thisOne.which == 88) {
             var x = document.querySelectorAll(".x");
             x.forEach(function(element){
                element.classList.add("disableMenu");
             });                     
         }
     }
    }

    function IEKeyCap() {
     if (window.event.shiftKey) {
         if (window.event.keyCode == 88) {
             var x = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
             x.classList.add("disableMenu");
         }
     }
    }

    if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
     window.captureEvents(Event.KEYPRESS);
     window.onKeyPress = NNKeyCap;
    }

    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
        x.classList.remove("disableMenu");
    }

    function myClickEvent(body)
    {
        var childDiv = body.querySelector('#wrapper');
        var hasClass = childDiv.classList.contains('disableMenu');
        if(hasClass)
        {
            document.location = 'http://www.google.com'; <!-- your background link here -->
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

here I removed the `onkeyup="myFunction()"` in body tag as it is removing the `disableMenu` class which is being added by `IEKeyCap`

and added `myClickEvent` which checks if `#wrapper` has class `disableMenu`
if it has `disableMenu` then it will be redirected to the link you assigned to `document.location`

Hope this helps you